# Search Bar in android

Tags: android

I want to add a search bar in my activity. I have some lat long stored in a vector and i want to search a lat long using search bar and want to animate map to that point.
How to do this?? Please give me some suggestion
thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to launch google maps for a particular lat long, it is possible to start activity using Intent.

Check for the intent details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html).

If you are drawing map in your application itself, then you can use the search bar. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html) is the documentation on how to do it.

Comment: thnx for giving kind suggestion